# Criar um exceção propositalmente

Tags: java, android

Consigo criar uma exceção dividindo um valor por 0 desta forma:

```
try {
    int res = 100/0;
} catch (Exception e){
    Log.wtf(TAG,"Test Exception");
}
```

Mas não sei se seria a forma mais viável. Como poderia criar uma exceção propositalmente? Qual seria a forma mais simples de criar uma exceção propositalmente?

Comment: Tenta usar a classe Exception `throw new Exception("Test Exception");`

Comment: `throw new ArithmeticException("divisão por 0...");`

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo do problema vc deve "customizar" uma exceção, além de ser uma boa prática te ajudar a ter um controle melhor sobre o código de sua aplicação.

Vou montar um exemplo para customizar uma exceção para divisão por zero.
O primeiro passo é cria uma classe estendendo a exceção que mais se assemelha a seu problema `IOException`, `ArithmeticException` entre outros.

```
public class DivisaoPorZeroException extends ArithmeticException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DivisaoPorZeroException() {
        super();
    }

    public DivisaoPorZeroException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

}
```

O segundo passo é criar o método que irá efetivamente efetuar uma operação e onde o ponto crítico que irá ser tratado pode ocorrer, neste ponto geralmente fica toda a lógica do problema, neste exemplo utilizei a divisão por zero, então com o domínio da técnica de divisão irei criar o método que faz somente a divisão, levando em consideração o erro que pode ser encontrado (dividir por zero):

```
public static double dividir(double dividendo, double divisor) throws DivisaoPorZeroException {
        if (divisor == 0) {
            throw new DivisaoPorZeroException("Divisor não pode ser zero");
        }
        return dividendo / divisor;
    }
```

Agora simplesmente testando seu resultado

```
        System.out.println(dividir(5D, 2D));
        System.out.println(dividir(5D, 0D));
```